# How to pass HttpClientHandler to existing HttpClient?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, httpclient, httpclienthandler

I have `HttpClient httpClient` injected from outside of my class.

Inside my class I'm creating a new HttpClientHandler `var handler = new HttpClientHandler()` and setting its values.

I need to link `HttpClientHandler` to existing `HttpClient` the same way you can do it using the [constructor: `new HttpClient(handler)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_Net_Http_HttpClient__ctor_System_Net_Http_HttpMessageHandler_)

Is it possible? I've tried looking for `HttpClientHandler` property within `HttpClient` but it does not exist. Is there any other way?

Comment: Have you customized the `httpClient` instance you're injecting?

Comment: `Is it possible?` No. Using Httpclient factory however, a client can be configured to use a specific handler. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests

Comment: This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that clarifies your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.